# Random Forest predicting neither class when target is one hot encoded

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, one-hot-encoding

I fairly know that trees are sensitive to one hot encoded (OHE) targets however I want to understand why it returns the predictions like this:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
            .
            .
            .
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

For most of the samples, it predict neither class. I will encode my targets as ordinal (since it is applicable)  but what if it was not? What to do then? This is how it looks before OHE:

```
array(['4 -8 weeks', '13 - 16 weeks', '17 - 20 weeks', ..., '9 - 12 weeks',
       '13 - 16 weeks'], dtype=object)
```

Full code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
mlb = LabelBinarizer()
b = mlb.fit_transform(Class)
list(mlb.classes_)

# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, b, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create a multi-label classifier
classifier = RandomForestClassifier()

# Train the classifier
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Make predictions on the test set
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: Ciao Apollonia, do you mind to share a [mcve]? In particular `data` and `b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the targets are one-hot encoded, sklearn treats the problem as a multi-label one (each row could have any number of labels).  As such, you get a predicted probability for each label, and those are independently thresholded at 0.5 in order to make the class predictions.

When the targets are ordinally encoded, sklearn treats the problem as a multiclass one (each row has exactly one class).  Despite the numerical ordering, *sklearn doesn't care* (well, except in tiebreaking) and treats the classes as unordered.  The predicted probabilities sum to 1, and the predicted class is the one with largest probability.

**You don't need to encode labels at all.**  sklearn will encode them internally for computational efficiency; but leaving strings as the labels is fine, will be treated as multiclass, and allows for the class predictions to also be strings (no need to decode).